# Cannot import TailwindCSS in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tailwind-css

Using React, NextJS, TailwindCSS(non JIT) and PostCSS. I'm trying to test React components in Jest with `@testing-library/jest-dom` and `@testing-library/react`.

```json
// jest.config.js
{
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', 'jest-test-results.json', 'cypress'],
  setupFiles: ['./tests/config.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./tests/config-after-env.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
}
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require("./src/styles/colors.js");

module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.js", "./src/**/*.jsx", "./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {...extend...},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp")],
};
```

I tried all the transformers I could find [jest-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-css-modules), [jest-transform-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-css), [jest-css-modules-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-css-modules-transform) but no luck. It always fails with un unexpected token in the tailwind import line.

Basically I want to test elements in the component based on CSS, ie.

```
expect(...).not.toBeVisible();
// click button to show element
expect(...).toBeVisible();
```

Comment: What's your tailwind.config.js look like?

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Is `theme: {...extend...},` what you literally have, or do you have a valid structure more along the lines of `theme: {extend: {colors:colors}},` which you don't want to share? Any difference if you use `theme: {extend: {}},` ?

Comment: It's also possible you're mixing tailwind v2 and v3 structures... `purge` was changed to `content` in v3.

Comment: Yes `theme` is valid, just shortened it on here. I will look into the content thing, thanks!

Comment: @apo_p9 did you find any resolution to your issue? I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: @Dennis unfortunately not

Comment: I'm also facing this same issue tried to follow this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74160802/20035351) but nothing resolved. everytime I'm receiving "ButtonFace" in console log.   @apo_p9 did you solve this problem? if it's please can you tell what should do??

Comment: @nuser137 That was a long time ago I think I just went with checking if a certain class is present. The solution from the question is exactly what I had thought about but didnt look into, looks reasonable.

Comment: yes @apo_p9, but after searching a lot I figured it out that "ButtonFace" is the default color of Button that we see in the browser and it is from CSS2. sorry I couldn't copy that SO link, cause I saw and removed that tab. anyways, to get solid color there is need to configure tailwind CSS or maybe mock it. not sure, I'll see it later on!