# React testing library can't read styles using Tailwind CSS classes

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tailwind-css, react-testing-library

I have a simple React component that will initially have a Tailwind CSS class of `hidden` which apply CSS `display: none` and will change the class to `visible` on button click.
When I test with `expect().not.toBeVisible()` it tells me the element is already visible while it has a `hidden` class.

If I don't use Tailwind CSS and use a normal `style={{display: 'none'}}` it'll correctly identify that the element isn't visible. That means clearly the issue is with Tailwind CSS.

Here's my test:

```js
test("Notification bar should be initially hidden but visible on click", async () => {
    render(<Notifications />);

    expect(await screen.findByTestId("list")).not.toBeVisible();
    // this test fails while the element already has a Tailwind CSS class of "hidden"
});
```

While this's my component:

```html
<ul className="hidden" data-testid="list">
  <li>item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not test the _class_, given the underlying styles won't be applied in unit tests?

Answer (score 6):

The solution explained in this [Stack Overflow: cannot check expectelm not tobevisible for semantic ui react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813527/cannot-check-expectelm-not-tobevisible-for-semantic-ui-react-component). Based on that thread, I extend the solution to make it works with TailwindCSS as the steps explained below,

### Project structure

```
root/
   src/
      test/
         index.css
         test-utils.tsx
         component.test.tsx
      index.css
```

### 1. Generate CSS from the TailwindCSS template files

By issuing the command below, the CSS file called `index.css` will be generated in `src/test` directory

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/test/index.css
```

Further reading: [TailwindCSS installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

### 2. Create custom render function

Next we need to inject the generated CSS file into the JSDOM. Custom render function will be useful so we won't be needed to repeat this task for each test

```
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';
import fs from 'fs';

const wrapper: FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  return <>{children}<>;
};

const customRender = (ui: ReactElement, options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>) => {
  const view = render(ui, { wrapper, ...options });

  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = fs.readFileSync('src/test/index.css', 'utf8');
  document.head.appendChild(style);

  return view;
};

export * from '@testing-library/react';
export { customRender as render };
```

Further reading: [Testing Library Setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup)

### 3. Perform testing, unit test suppose to be success now

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from './test-utils';

test('Renders hidden hello world', () => {
  render(<span className="hidden">Hello World</span>);
  expect(screen.getByText('Hello World')).not.toBeVisible();
});
```

### Why souldn't we use `toHaveClass` matchers instead?

it wouldn't align with the Testing Library guiding principle of ***“emphasize a focus on tests that closely resemble how your web pages are interacted by the users“*** because by doing so, you are interacting with the component unnaturally

Comment: it doesn't work for me :( I guess without configuring tailwind css, can't test tailwind css classes anymore!

Comment: While this works I find that it makes the test performance too slow. Most end up timing out.

Answer (score 4):

##### This solution works well for NextJS 13 application

Use `css:true` in `vitest.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { configDefaults } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    },
  },
  test: {
    // this option
    css: true,
    setupFiles: ['./tests/setupTests.ts'],
    ...
  }
});
```

See more here: https://vitest.dev/config/#css

and then import your main CSS file in `setupTests.ts`

```js
import '@/src/styles/globals.css';
```

where `global.css` starts with:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Vite as your bundler and Vitest as the testing framework, you can use the `css: true` option in the Vitest options to enable processing CSS in test files. See more here: https://vitest.dev/config/#css

Additionally, you will have to import your `index.css` (or whatever path name it is) in your component test or, even better, in your Vitest `setupTests` file.

Answer (score 0):

> I also encountered the same situation and tried to follow this [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74160802/20035351) many times but nothing happened.

For me what it worked I tried to solve this by mocking the `tailwind CSS` from node modules, like this:

- **jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
      moduleNameMapper: {
        //.. all mocks names
        '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/tailwindcss',
      },
}
```

I hope this someone helps!